# Pogo pin version of ISP cable for AVR mega8 in TQFP-32 package

Tags: avr, isp, tqfp, pogo-pins

- There are a few 6pin and 10pin pogo variants of Atmel ISP adapters that require dedicated ISP pogo pads on the PCB.
- There are full TQFP-32 ZIF sockets that can be used to program any AVR in that package, but it needs to be done before soldering to the PCB.

However, there is something like a pogo connector that goes directly over the TQFP-32 package (after it was soldered to the PCB and doesn't require dedicated ISP pogo pads) and has a pinout that allows the mega8/mega88 (and probably some other AVRs which have ISP on the same pins) to be programmed with ISP. I had one in the past and I know it exists. But no matter how I'm searching for it I fail to find it. Does anybody know how it's exactly called or where to buy it? On the other side, it ends with a ribbon cable and ISP 10 female pin header socket.

The adapter looks something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5unHRB2sV4

But can't find anybody selling it, I think before it was all over the ebay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hobbyking used to sell them, but it's been discontinued apparently. It looked like [this](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/atmel-atmega-socket-firmware-flashing-tool.html):

[image]

You could search to see if anyone still has it in stock, or if you have access to a milling machine with a DRO and a handful of one of the smaller sizes pogo pins it would not be hard to duplicate the business end from a small chunk of acetal plastic or other suitable material and solder a cable with heat shrink onto it. The TQFP is fairly crude at 0.8mm lead pitch so it does not require the skills of a master machinist.

Comment: Thank you, I might try to make PCBs and stack them.